# Database query info to dropdown menu

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, drop-down-menu

I am taking info from a database query and adding it to a dropdown menu form (that is placed inside a table).  The query is in a separate function that is called from within the form.  It adds the info from the database to the correct location on the table, but it is not in the dropdown menu.  I used variables $a, $b, and $c to test my syntax, and it works fine with those variables.  Is it an issue with the function call?  Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
function fill_dropdown(){
include("../secure/database.php");          
$conn = pg_connect(HOST." ".DBNAME." ".USERNAME." ".PASSWORD)
or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error()); //error if could not connect to database

$query = "SELECT country_code, name FROM lab5.country ORDER BY name ASC";

$result = pg_query($query) or die("Unable to execute: " . pg_last_error($conn));

$numRow = 0;
    //results are good so output them to HTML
//echo "test<br />";
while ($line1 = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
    $counter = 0;
    //echo "test<br />";
    foreach ($line1 as $col_value){ // then add all data for attributes in succeeding columns
        if($counter == 0){
            $code[$numRow] = $col_value;//array($numRow => $col_value);
            echo "\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"code\" value=\"$code[$numRow]\" />";
            //echo $code[$numRow] . "<br />";
        }
        elseif($counter == 1){
            $country_name[$numRow] = $col_value;
            echo "<option value=$country_name[$numRow]>$country_name[$numRow]</option>";
            //echo $country_name[$numRow] . "<br />";
        }
        $counter++;
    }
    $numRow++;
}
//echo "end test<br />";
}




echo "<table border = \"1\">";
echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"exec.php\">";                  //save and cancel buttons
for($i=1; $i<5; $i++)       //building initial table
{
echo "\t<tr>\n";
echo "\t\t<td>";
if($i == 1)
    echo "Name";
elseif($i == 2)
    echo "Country Code";
elseif($i == 3)
    echo "District";
else
    echo "Population";
echo "</td>\n";

echo "<td>\n";

if($i == 1){
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\">";
}
elseif($i == 2){
    echo "<select name=\"country_code\">";              //dropdown box
    $c = 0;    //these are just to show that this way works
    $a = "IOT";
    $b = "test2";
    $numRow = 1;
    echo "<option value=\"IOT\">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>";
    echo "<option value=$a>$b</option>";
    //echo "<option value=" . $country_name[$numRow] . ">" . $country_name[$numRow] . "</option>";
    fill_dropdown();
    //echo "<option value=\"Brunei\">Brunei</option>";
    echo "</select>";
}
elseif($i == 3){
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"district\">";
}
else{
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"population\">";
}
}
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";                                    
echo "\t\t<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\" name=\"save\" />";      
echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\" onclick=\"top.location.href='" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "';\" />\n";
echo "</form>";


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem you can replace

```
while ($line1 = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
    $counter = 0;
    //echo "test<br />";
    foreach ($line1 as $col_value){ // then add all data for attributes in succeeding columns
        if($counter == 0){
            $code[$numRow] = $col_value;//array($numRow => $col_value);
            echo "\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"code\" value=\"$code[$numRow]\" />";
            //echo $code[$numRow] . "<br />";
        }
        elseif($counter == 1){
            $country_name[$numRow] = $col_value;
            echo "<option value=$country_name[$numRow]>$country_name[$numRow]</option>";
            //echo $country_name[$numRow] . "<br />";
        }
        $counter++;
    }
    $numRow++;
}
```

with

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // why do you want this line at all?
    echo "\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"code\" value=\"$row[country_code]\"/>";
    echo "<option value=\"$row[name]\">$row[name]</option>";
}
```

The only thing I can see that is wrong, is not having quotes around the option's value attribute. I don't understand what you are expecting to achieve by interleaving hidden inputs with options, though. Judging by your `$a, $b, $c` template, maybe what you actually want is:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<option value=\"$row[country_code]\">$row[name]</option>";
}
```

Comment: Wow, you hit the nail on the head.  The idea of $code[$numRow] is to insert that as the value for the option.  I did need to use the original code, but I got rid of the hidden input and changed the option line to:

    '<option value="' . $code[$numRow] . '">' . $country_name[$numRow] . '</option>';

and it works perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: @Bill I don't see why you are building up the arrays `$code` and `$country_name` at all. Can't you replace it all with the loop in my last answer?

Comment: You're right.  I just tried it and it worked.  I am still new to php and postgresql.  I didn't realize it was that easy to sift through the data from the query.